# Jquey não funciona com elementos inseridos usando .html()

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

Boa noite gente, então.. Tenho um código ajax que pega um loop dentro de um arquivo php e depois insere o resultado dentro de uma página html. Até aí, tudo funciona. O problema é na hora que quero manipular alguma classe que foi inserida usando .html() do jquery, que ele simplesmente não faz nada. Como se aquela classe não existisse.

Código php:

```
if ($stmt->num_rows != 0) {

while($stmt->fetch()) {

  $info = substr($info, 0, 100);

  echo '<div>
      <a class="uk-link-reset" href="detalhes?id='.$id.'">
      <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-hover">
        <div class="uk-card-media-top">
          <img class="imagem_produto" src="'.$imagem.'">
        </div>
        <div class="uk-card-body">
          <h6>'.$nome_categoria.'</h6>
          <h2 class="uk-card-title uk-margin-small-top">'.$nome.'</h2>
          <p class="uk-text-justify">'.$info.'...</p>
          <div class="uk-grid-collapse uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center" uk-grid>
            <div>
              <div class="uk-background-muted uk-padding-small">R$ '.$valor_novo.'</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </a>
  </div>';

}

}
```

Código do ajax:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'html',
url: 'processos/produtos.php',
success: function(data) {
  $(".produtos").html(data);
}
});
```

Daí se eu faço, um simples:

```
$(".uk-text-justify").click(function(){alert('algo')});
```

Não funciona.

Comment: Se o `$(".uk-text-justify").click(function(){alert('algo')});` é executado antes do *ajax* então os elementos que vem do ajax não vão ter o handler de click. Isso é um problema de delegação, e já tem várias perguntas aqui disso: [problema-com-evento-onload](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156472/problema-com-evento-onload) , [nao-consigo-remover-os-campos-que-acabei-de-colocar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12969/n%C3%A3o-consigo-remover-os-campos-que-acabei-de-colocar) , entre outras

Comment: Mas ele é executado depois.

Comment: Quando disse executado, refiro-me especificamente em atribuir o handler de click => definir qual o código para o click e não especificamente o ato de clickar no elemento.

Comment: Exatamente. Ele é executado após o elemento ser definido na página.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforme isso:

```
$(".uk-text-justify").click(function(){alert('algo')});
```

Nisso:

```
$(document).on("click", ".uk-text-justify", function(){ 
    alert('algo');
});
```

Comment: Perfeito. Ajudou muito.